# Numbers OCR (Optical Recognition) in javascript

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, tensorflow.js

I am looking for Javascript API for OCR or Machine Learning example (Tensorflow.js or any other) which can recognize numbers from the picture. I tried tesseract.js and OCRAD.js, but both do not work well with this kind of image. I only need numbers from this picture like 2.243 and 0048. I also put to tesseract.js settings, that it is numbers only, but it did not help much.

The picture is a photo of the digital device, which does not have API to connect and get data digitally. I would like to use webcam and javascript OCR and get these numbers periodically from this device to the list and build the graphs later.

I found a lot of examples for Tensorflow recognition of handwritten digits, but all of them can recognize only one digit, they cannot recognize a number consisting of more than 1 digits.

P.S. I do not want to spend a lot of time, actually I do not have this time :). Just want to reuse ready example.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used AWS Rekognition and Azure Cognitive Services. Both perform well in terms of accuracy. I found Azure's HTTP model simpler.

Please bear in mind that both Azure and AWS have different offerings for extracting printed text (OCR) and text inside pictures.

**Azure**

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200

**Steps for configuring Azure Cognitive Services**

- You will need to sign up with Microsoft's Azure portal
- Log in to https://portal.azure.com
- Click on the "+Create Resource" link on the top left
- Type the word "Cognitive" and hit ENTER
- This should bring up "Cognitive Services"
- You will be presented with a form . Select Name, Subscription, pricing tier, location, etc.
- You may have to create a Subscription before reaching the above step. I do not remember how.
- Once done with the above, you will be presented with the URL and app key
- You can now use the REST api to upload PNG files and get back a JSON with the text
- I also found this URL which gives you the option for a free trial . https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/
- Link to code documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text

**AWS Rekognition**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detection.html

This is what I got from AWS Rekognition by using your image

[image]

**EAST text detector**

You could give this a try.  OpenCV embeds this. You will have to set up your back end service.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5asMTdhmvA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfiCmhLLxMA

Comment: Azur looks like not free and there is no javascript implementation. Only java, C#, etc.

Aws also does not look free.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The cloud based providers will give you some free usage but you will have to pay for anything beyond that.

Comment: We are using the HTTP end point of Azure. You could use the strongly typed client libraries too for coding simplicity (c#, java).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtocallvisionapi

Comment: You have to remember that calling the Azure/AWS services from the browser, even though technically possible, would expose the API keys to the end user. You can make it hard but I see no way to prevent their theft. You would want to route the calls to Azure/AWS/etc. through your back end.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Yes, from network tab in browser debug tools it will be very easier to get the key. I need it for personal use, it will not be available to the internet. And because it is for personal use, I am afraid to use these guys (MS, AWS, Google offers same and it works better than Azure), because at some point they might charge me. 
Will see, now I am more into implementing my own javascript, based on tensor flow or ML5js, just to recognize digits. I will need to split the image to N digits and train it with, but it is only 10 digits to train. Should not be very difficult.